# p-calendar not working on IE, Edge and Firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using primeng p-calendar it's OK on google-chrome but it won't work (date-picker not opening text-box click) on any other browsers.

here is my html code that I used :

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="startDate" showIcon="true" monthNavigator="true" yearNavigator="true" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" dataType="yearRange="1970:2030"></p-calendar>
```

and here is where I initialize *starDate* variable in typescript :

```
const dateParts = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString().split('/');
this.startDate = dateParts[1] + '/' + dateParts[0] + '/' + dateParts[2];
```

I see primeng calendar on their website is working fine on any browser, But if I was doing wrong why it's OK on google-chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p-calendar`'s value should be JS Date object and not a string, so try to set your start date value like this:

```
this.startDate = new Date();
```

`dateFormat` only defines how dates will be presented in the calendar